# How to create bootable flash drive from macOS High Sierra combo update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, high-sierra, bootable-disk

I have problem installing macOS High Sierra from App Store. I don't understand what the problem is, but when the download completes it suddenly resets. Then when I open up App Store again it only lets download the os again.

I want to clean reinstall High Sierra on my Mac and the only way to do it is to create bootable flash drive because I have a bad internet connection.

I have downloaded macOS High Sierra combo update with a download manager, and my question is can I create bootable flash drive with this combo update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot create a **macOS USB Installer** from the **Combo Update**, you need the full **Install macOS High Sierra.app** to do that.

Have a look at: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)

If you cannot get it to download properly on your system using your connection, then you'll have to try from a different location and connection or have a friend download it, or go to an Apple Store.

Comment: So how can i download it, as i said when it finishes the download it reset and I can't do anything.